# EIP1167. why this special address?

Tags: eip

https://github.com/optionality/clone-factory/blob/master/contracts/CloneFactory.sol

at this file.

```
  function createClone(address target) internal returns (address result) {
    bytes20 targetBytes = bytes20(target);
    assembly {
      let clone := mload(0x40)
      mstore(clone, 0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x14), targetBytes)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x28), 0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000)
      result := create(0, clone, 0x37)
    }
  }
```

i know mstore mean. but why must this special address?
0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000

0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

They are not addresses they are bytecode.

The first part `3d602d80600a3d3981f3` is an optimized constructor

```
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
60  PUSH1 0x2d
80  DUP1
60  PUSH1 0x0a
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
39  CODECOPY
81  DUP2
F3  *RETURN
```

It indicates that from byte 10 (0x0a) with length 45 (0x2d) is the bytecode to be deployed.

The second part `363d3d373d3d3d363d73` is the start of the bytecode. The target address is concatenated at the end of this part. It prepares to make a call to the target address.

```
36  CALLDATASIZE
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
37  CALLDATACOPY
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
36  CALLDATASIZE
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
73  PUSH20 <TargetAddress>
```

The last part `5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf3` makes a delegatecall, returns requested data if the call was successful or reverts if it failed.

```
5A  GAS
F4  DELEGATECALL
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
82  DUP3
80  DUP1
3E  RETURNDATACOPY
90  SWAP1
3D  RETURNDATASIZE
91  SWAP2
60  PUSH1 0x2b
57  JUMPI
FD  REVERT
5B  JUMPDEST
F3  RETURN
```

Note: RETURNDATASIZE is a cheap way to push a zero byte when no call has been made.

Note 2: Read the [EIP 1167 - Minimal Proxy Contract](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167) for other details.